# Are inherited destructors contained inside the virtual table?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

In case my compiler is using virtual tables, how will the virtual table of B look like? Will `A::~A` be inside `B`'s virtual table?

```
struct A{
    virtual ~A()
    {
        cout<<"A::destructor"<<endl;
    }
};
struct B:public A{
    ~B()
    {
        cout<<"B::destructor"<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried running that code yourself?

Comment: yes, virtual d'tor address is in the vtable.

Comment: Why would the vtable of B have `~A` in it?

Comment: hi, yes. the code works as expected but I still doesn't know the answer..

Comment: Virtual Tables are an implementation detail.  You need to look on your platform. Also you don't say what your platform is.

Comment: my platform is c9 - ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't have `~A` in the virtual table of `B`. It will have `~B` in the entry that corresponds with the destructor. After all, once a destructor is declared virtual, all deriving destructors are virtual.

So a `delete` expression will call the correct destructor always. The way the base sub-object `A` of `B` is destroyed, can be accomplished simply by the compiler *statically* injecting a call to `~A` at the end of `~B`. Conceptually like this:

```
~B()
{
    cout<<"B::destructor"<<endl;

    //User defined code ended. Compiler generated one is here
    static_cast<A*>(this)->A::~A();
}
```

This is all delving deeply into *possible* implementation details. None of this is covered by the C++ standard itself.

Comment: `static_cast<A*>(this)->~A();` calls destructor of B. It should be rather `this->A::~A();`.

Comment: @NO_NAME - Changed. But this *is* conceptual pseudo code, after all.